# How do I add a drop down menu to a border layout in Qt

Tags: qt

I have created a border layout, and I have created a menu layout following these two tutorials:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/mainwindows-menus.html
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layouts-borderlayout.html

I am missing something fundamental when I try to put them together. My result is an application window with nothing in it. The border layout worked fine on its own as well as the menu (pulled straight from the reference).

What's the best way to add a drop down menu to the border layout?

Comment: What have you done so far? Isolate the problem and post this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the menu example as a basis. Use the `Window` class from the other example instead of `widget` in the `MainWindow` constructor, so

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
  setCentralWidget(widget);
```

becomes

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  Window *widget = new Window;
  setCentralWidget(widget);
```